# Expectation for non-negative r.v

Tags: probability, probability-theory

suppose I have

$$\sum_{n=0}^{0} P(X=k)$$

Would this evaluate to $P(X=0)$ or $0$?

In general, from my understanding:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{k} P(X=k) = (k + 1)P(X=k)$$. Is this correct?

I ask in this scenario, of proving that for a non-negative discrete random variable

$$E(X) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X\ge n)$$

My professor said we can ignore $n = 0$, since it's summand is 0, but I am not sure about this -- because $P(X = 0)$ can be non-zero.

Comment: Your professor probably meant that we can ignore $n=0$ term in the sum $\mathbb EX = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n \mathbb P(X=n)$ and that is why $\mathbb EX = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X \ge n)$ starts from $n=1$.

Comment: That's exactly right @Presage. I think in that case $n = 1$ *must* be the starting point. Do you know how this relates to the more general $E(G(X)) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g(n) P(X \ge n)$? For this, he mentioned it would need to start at $n = 0$ (I know $G(k) = \sum_{n=0}^k g(n)$ for this to be true)

Comment: Because $g(0)$ need not be zero and in that case we need this $g(0)\mathbb P(X=0)$ term.

Comment: So for our original one @Presage, I think $g(n) = 0$ for $n = 0$ and $g(n) = 1$ otherwise, but if I am understanding it correctly as the "derivative", then I don't see why it should be 0 at a point.

Answer (score 1):

> suppose I have
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{0} P(X=k)$$
>
> Would this evaluate to $P(X=0)$ or $0$?

In this case, $P(X=0)$. In general,
$$
\sum_{i=a}^b x_i = x_a + x_{a+1} + \cdots + x_b
$$
Notice that the lower and upper bounds are, in fact, included.

$P(X=k)$ does not depend on $n$ in this case, but you can think of this as being a summand that's constant with respect to the index, say like
$$
\sum_{i=a}^b 2
$$
which you can factor out of the summation and get a summation of $1$'s if you please. Correspondingly:

> In general, from my understanding:
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{k} P(X=k) = (k + 1)P(X=k)$$. Is this correct?

This is correct.

> I ask in this scenario, of proving that for a non-negative discrete random variable
>
> $$E(X) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X\ge n)$$
>
> My professor said we can ignore $n = 0$, since it's summand is 0, but I am not sure about this -- because $P(X = 0)$ can be non-zero.

A more accurate statement, sort of, would be
$$
E(X) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X > n)
$$
as loosely derived [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#:%7E:text=Formulas%20in%20terms%20of%20CDF). This equality can be seen as coming from an integral/measure-theoretic formulation of integral, for which this summation is a special case for nonnegative r.v.s. But then $n=0$ is just never a concern: it never appears in the formula.

You're right that $P(X=0)$ could be nonzero. I imagine your professor was thinking of the formula/definition
$$
E(X) := \sum_n n P(X=n)
$$
for which the summand for $n=0$ does indeed have value $0$ (because of the weighting factor $n$, as opposed to the probability).